# CSS property: Behavior of my property doesn't apply

Tags: css

I have got an image directly in my html which is a little profile picture and I am trying to move this image on the top right corner of my website but no matter what property I put the image it doesn't move.

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif, Arial;
  background-image: url(image/background1.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.first_part {
  text-align: center;
}

.flottant {
  background: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_part">
  <h1>Roger Albert</h1>
  <p>Entrepreneur, auteur et co-fondateur d'OpenClassrooms</p>
</div>
<img src="image/13531.png" class="flottant" alt="Profil picture" />
```

Comment: You don't move things with `background`, but with `position` and any of the properties `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this. You should look into CSS flexbox for more control over your positioning.  But for now you can use `position: relative` `float: right` and `bottom: 75px` as a very simple way to do this. See the snippet:

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif, Arial;
  background-image: url(image/background1.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.first_part {
  text-align: center;
}

.flottant {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_part">
  <h1>Roger Albert</h1>
  <p>Entrepreneur, auteur et co-fondateur d'OpenClassrooms</p>
</div>
<img src="image/13531.png" class="flottant" alt="Profil picture" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have this "all over the place a bit" :) Try reading up some tutorials on the basics of HTML and CSS, but basically what you want to do is:

1. Wrap your image in a container:

   `<body>
       <div id="container">
           <img src="image/13531.png" class="flottant"  alt="Profil picture"/>
       </div>
   </body>`
2. Give the container the `position:relative;` property, and give the element you want to position `position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;`.
3. Make both the body and container a certain size, like the 100% of the viewport using `body, #container { width:100%; height:100%; }`.

Please look at your own code, where in the `body` tag you are using different attributes from the background family. If you wanted to set the position of the background (although it would not work in this case because your image is not a background, rather a HTML tag in itself), you would use `background-position: top right;`.

I recommend https://www.w3schools.com/.